# Proving a question on connectivity of topological subspaces

Tags: general-topology

I have been trying to solve the following question:

*Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ a subspace of $X$, that is connected (in the relative topology). Show that if $Z$ is any subspace of $X$, such that $Y \subseteq Z \subseteq \bar{Y}$, ($\bar{Y}$ is the closure of $Y$), then $Z$ is connected.*

I have tried to proceed in what I think is the standard way to approach this problem by assuming that $Z$ is disconnected and then proceeding to find a contradiction. $Z$ being disconnected implies that there $\exists$ non-empty closed sets $H,K$ of $X$, such that, (a): $Z \subseteq H \cup K$, (b): $Z \cap H$, $Z \cap K$ are non empty and disjoint.  Also since $Y \subseteq Z \subseteq \bar{Y}$, this implies that
(c): $\bar{Y}= \bar{Z}$.

I am now having trouble looking for a contradiction. For instance if I can prove that $Z$ being disconnected implies that $\bar{Z}=\bar{Y}$ is disconnected, then using the fact that the closure of a connected set is connected would solve the problem. But I am not able to see how I would be able to prove that using the sets $H$ and $K$. Now $Z \cap H $, $Z \cap K$ being non empty implies the intersection of each $H$ and $K$ with $\bar{Y}$ is non empty, but we can't say that they are disjoint. Any leads on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to obtain a contradiction by using the fact that $Y$ is connected.

**HINT**: The above hypothesis forces $Y \subset H$ or $Y\subset K$.

Comment: Ah, so WLOG let us assume $Y \subset H $. Then this implies $ \bar{Y}= \bar{Z} \subset \bar{H}=H$ since $H$ is closed. Also, since $\bar{Z} \subset H$ this implies $Z \subset H$, and so $Z \cap H =Z$. Now there would be a contradiction with point (b).

Comment: Yes that is correct.